# Parsing JSON data in android

Tags: android

Hello am trying to get the "Percent" value from the below JSON in android but unable to parse it correctly.

```
{
  "Percent": 100,
  "ErrorCode": null,
  "ErrorNiceMessage": "",
  "Warnings": [],
  "Info": null,
  "FormErrors": [],
  "State": true,
}
```

My Code is as below but am getting blank value. Can you please advise.

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message);
JSONArray arr = reader.getJSONArray("Percent");
i = arr.getString(0);
```

Comment: 'Percent' is a key referred to a integer value not to a json array

Comment: There is no need to parse today this way. Use **GSONFormat** plugin and create model class from json.

Comment: @darwin is right pls look into this.

Comment: Percent  is a integer so try to get like this JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message);   int percentValue=reader.getInt("Percent")

Comment: look at tutorials in [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/106/json-in-android-with-org-json#t=201703111134534454361) section

Comment: Thank you @sarath

Comment: Am trying to parse data from gateway.pusulacc.com.tr/api/developer/dashboard. Am trying to get value of element "ServisServiyesi". When I enter below code it says no value exists: JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message); i = reader.getDouble("ServisServiyesi");

Comment: better solution.. use Gson and POJO class..

Comment: Your JSON code is not valid anyway: the comma after `"State": true` is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message);
i = reader.getInt("Percent");
```

Comment: Now am trying to parse data from gateway.pusulacc.com.tr/api/developer/dashboard. Am trying to get value of element "ServisServiyesi". When I enter below code it says no value exists: JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message); i = reader.getDouble("ServisServiyesi");

Comment: JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message);
JSONObject jsonObject = reader.getJSONObject("Result");
i = jsonObject.getDouble("ServisServiyesi");

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Percent is not a JSON Array , it's a key which refers integer value.

Try this way :

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message);
int percentValue = reader.getInt("Percent");
```

Comment: Thanks. Now am trying to get parse data from http://gateway.pusulacc.com.tr/api/developer/dashboard. 
Am trying to get value of element "ServisServiyesi". When I enter below code it says no value exists:
 
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message);
i = reader.getDouble("ServisServiyesi");

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message);
i = reader.optInt("Percent",0);// opt int will help you if Percent value is null then you will get default value as 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse data from [gateway.pusulacc.com.tr/api/developer/dashboard](http://gateway.pusulacc.com.tr/api/developer/dashboard)

Use this code

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONObject resultObj= data.getJsonObject("Result");
double doubleValue=resultObj.getDouble("ServisServiyesi");
```